# How to fix ConcurrentModificationException while operating LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I was trying to make a playlist belonging to **"Song"** class having fields-(`String`) **'title'** and  (int) **'duration'**. It doesn't have any compilation error but throws `ConcurrentModificationException` whenever I try to operate list.

I've tried to operate on a copy of the list but it didn't work.
I've read that use of for loop throws this error but I'm only using `Iterator`:

```
while (!quit) {
        int input = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        switch (input) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("exiting");
                quit = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (!goingforward) {
                    if (listIterator.hasNext())
                        listIterator.next();
                    goingforward = true;
                }
                if (listIterator.hasNext())
                    System.out.println("now playng: " + 
listIterator.next().getTitle());
                else {
                    System.out.println("At end of the list");
                    goingforward = false;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (goingforward) {
                    if (listIterator.hasPrevious())
                        listIterator.previous();
                    goingforward = false;
                }
                if (listIterator.hasNext())
                    System.out.println("Now playing: " + 
listIterator.previous().getTitle());
                else {

                    System.out.println("At top of the list");
                    goingforward = true;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (goingforward)
                    System.out.println("Now playing: " + 
listIterator.previous().getTitle());
                else
                    System.out.println("Now playing: " + 
listIterator.next().getTitle());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid");

        }
```

Expected:
Traverse through a list of songs added to the playlist with output:
 Now playing Why we live

1(INPUT)

Now playing Save Me

Output:

Now playing Why we live

1.Skip to forward

2.Skip to Previous

3.replay

1. quit

1(INPUT)

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:970)
>     at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:892)
>     at Mian.main(Mian.java:49)

Comment: Please read up on posting an [mcve] - your code is incomplete and also too long for demonstrating your problem

Comment: `Mian.java:49` suggests problem is in `Mian.java` file at line 49. Can you point it out?

Comment: Anyway ConcurrentModificationException usually appears when we modify collection but not via iterator. So if you have something like `iterator = collection.iterator(); while(...){...collection.remove(currentElement);...}` you should change it into `while(..){...iterator.remove();..}`.

Comment: Code
Is incomplete not enough imfo

Comment: The post is indeed incomplete, as there is no code that shows when you're modifying the list while it's iterating, hence getting ConcurrentModificationException.

I will leave you the Oracle Doc about the Exception so you can see it more detailed:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Answer (score -1):

A `LinkedList` is not thread safe.
I suggest using a data structure that **is** thread like `Vector`.

Note that using thread safe data structures will impact performance.

Other than `Vector` which is a legacy class you can find many data structures in the `java.util.concurrent` package, see what suits your needs. You can find them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).